# ViewHolder pattern issue. Same OnClickListener set for all buttons inside ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener, android-viewholder

I can't figure out where am I wrong. I have created a button inside my custom ListView Adapter, I have implemented the ViewHolder pattern and set up an OnClickListener for the button.

The problem is, whenever I click on the button on any row, I get the same result for clicks. Same title, same username.

What else to I need to set up? Thanks and Merry Christmas!

Custom ListView adapter:

```
public FeedListViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<FeedItemsSetter> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

static class ViewHolder {        
    ImageView image;
    public TextView postTitle;
    public TextView postCateg;
    public TextView userInfo;
    public TextView likerNames;
    public ImageView feedUserImage;
    public Button feedLike;
    public Button feedShare;
    public Button likeButton;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    //ViewHolder holder = null;
    // test as field, maybe problem
    item = data.get(position);

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.postTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.postTitle);
        holder.postCateg = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.postCateg);
        holder.userInfo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.feedUserName);
        holder.likerNames = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.likerNames);
        holder.feedUserImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.feedUserImage);
        holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.feedLike = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.feedLike);
        holder.feedShare = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.feedShareBtn);
        holder.likeButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.feedLike);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();

    holder.postTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.postCateg.setText(item.getCategory());
    holder.userInfo.setText(item.getUser());
    holder.likerNames.setText(item.getLiker());
    holder.likerNames.setTag(item.getLikersLong());

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + item.getUserId()
                    + "/picture?type=large")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .transform(new RoundedTransformation(90, 4)).resize(100, 100)
            .centerCrop().into(holder.feedUserImage);

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load("http://www.edmondvarga.com/gastrolove/uploads/"
                    + item.getImage()).into(holder.image);

    holder.likerNames.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //mListener.onNamesClick(v.getTag().toString());
        }
    });

    holder.feedLike.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            System.out.println(item.getUser() + item.getTitle());

    });

    return row;
}

public void setCallback(facebookShareListener mListener) {
    this.mListener = mListener;
}

public static interface facebookShareListener {
    public void onSharePressed(String title, String imagename, String userId);

    public void onNamesClick(String title);
}

}
```

Comment: Move `item = data.get(position)` after `getTag()`

Comment: @MD no diference, still I get the same name for all clicks.

Comment: @EdmondTamas by name you are referring to this `mListener.onNamesClick(v.getTag().toString());`?

Comment: @Raghunandan - no, here is the test for the button: holder.feedLike.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    System.out.println(item.getUser() + item.getTitle());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare ViewHolder outside of the if-else statement :

```
ViewHolder holder;

if (row == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    row.setTag(holder);
}else{
    holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
}
```

Define position as final so you can access particular item index inside click :

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       holder.feedLike.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println(data.get(position).getUser() + data.get(position).getTitle());
       });
}
```

Comment: @EdmondTamas,Glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

> Same OnClickListener set for all buttons inside ArrayAdapter

Use same instance of `ViewHolder` for setting on setOnClickListener as:

```
 ViewHolder holder;
   if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.postTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.postTitle);
        .....

        row.setTag(holder);
    }else{
      holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
     holder.postTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
```