# On Click issue with ViewHolder pattern but not with getView

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-viewholder

I'm changing my adapter code from the basic `getView()` to `ViewHolder` pattern. My adapter has one `TextView`, one `ImageView` and one `ImageButton`. Everything looks fine but i'm having some problems with the `ImageButton`. I'll post both my code (the one with `getView()` and the other with `ViewHolder`). 
The one with `getView()` works perfectly, so i'm asking here cause i can't understand where i'm doing wrong in the `ViewHolder`'s `ImageButton`.

**Adapter class with getView()**

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Manga> {
    private final Context context;
    private List<Manga> list;
    DatabaseHandler dh;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ArrayList<MangaPreferito> mangaPrefAL;
    int current_id = 0;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, List<Manga> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.listadapter, list);

        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View rowView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listadapter, parent, false);

        dh = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db = dh.getWritableDatabase();
        mangaPrefAL = dh.getAllPreferiti(db);

        TextView titolo = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView immagine = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final ImageButton ibFavorite = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        if (list.get(position).getFavorite()) {
            ibFavorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_star);
        } else {
            ibFavorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_icon_no);
        }

        for (MangaPreferito m : mangaPrefAL) {
            if (list.get(position).getI().equals(m.getI())) {
                list.get(position).setFavorite(true);
            }
        }
        //HERE ONCLICK WORKS WELL

        ibFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (MangaPreferito m : mangaPrefAL) {
                    if (list.get(position).getI().equals(m.getI())) {
                        current_id = m.getId();
                    }
                }

                if (list.get(position).getFavorite()) {
                    list.get(position).setFavorite(false);
                    ibFavorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_icon_no);
                    dh.deleteManga(current_id, db);
                } else {
                    list.get(position).setFavorite(true);
                    ibFavorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_star);
                    dh.addPreferito(new MangaPreferito(list.get(position).getA(),
                            Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(list.get(position).getH())),
                            list.get(position).getI(),
                            list.get(position).getIm(),
                            Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(list.get(position).getLd())),
                            Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(list.get(position).getS())), list.get(position).getT()), db);

                }
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

**Adapter class with ViewHolder**

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Manga> {
    private final Context context;
    private List<Manga> list;
    DatabaseHandler dh;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ArrayList<MangaPreferito> mangaPrefAL;
    int current_id = 0;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, List<Manga> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.listadapter, list);

        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView titolo;
        ImageView immagine;
        ImageButton ibFavorite;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View rowView, ViewGroup parent) {
        dh = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db = dh.getWritableDatabase();
        mangaPrefAL = dh.getAllPreferiti(db);

        if(rowView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listadapter, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.titolo = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            viewHolder.immagine = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            viewHolder.ibFavorite = (ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }


        if(list.get(position).getFavorite()){
            viewHolder.ibFavorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_star);
        }else{
            viewHolder.ibFavorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_icon_no);
        }

        for(MangaPreferito m : mangaPrefAL){
            if (list.get(position).getI().equals(m.getI())) {
                list.get(position).setFavorite(true);
            }
        }

        //HERE ONCLICK DOESN'T WORK

        viewHolder.ibFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for(MangaPreferito m : mangaPrefAL){
                    if (list.get(position).getI().equals(m.getI())) {
                        current_id = m.getId();
                    }
                }

                if(list.get(position).getFavorite()){
                    list.get(position).setFavorite(false);
                    viewHolder.ibFavorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favorite_icon_no);
                    dh.deleteManga(current_id, db);
                }else{
                    list.get(position).setFavorite(true);
                    viewHolder.ibFavorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_star);
                    dh.addPreferito(new MangaPreferito(list.get(position).getA(),
                            Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(list.get(position).getH())),
                            list.get(position).getI(),
                            list.get(position).getIm(),
                            Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(list.get(position).getLd())),
                            Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(list.get(position).getS())),list.get(position).getT()), db);

                }
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

As you can see the code inside `onClick()` is the same but with `ViewHolder` it doesn't work, can someone explain me why? 
P.s. If you need more code or classes tell me and i'll edit my answer.

Comment: What does not work? Does the onclick gets called or not? Also have a look at a possible duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633967/viewholder-pattern-issue-same-onclicklistener-set-for-all-buttons-inside-arraya

As it says there move out the declaration of the viewholder outside the if statement. But it must be more clear what exactly is not working

Comment: As you can see the Viewholder is outside the if statement. Simply it adds this background to wrong elements, but i'll follow the answer of @Greg Ennis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow this strategy to properly use click listeners with the view holder pattern:

- Make your OnClickListener a member of your class, outside the scope of the `getView(...)` call. This will ensure you dont have problems with thinking you have closures (so you dont need position to be declared `final` anymore).
- Set your click listener only when `rowView==null` and the view is inflated, not on every call.
- In your click handler, call `getTag` on the view clicked to access the ViewHolder. Everything you need to use should be in the view holder. If not, add it.

Follow this strategy will well prepare you to convert to `RecyclerView` if you ever need to - maybe now would be a good time.

Comment: I followed your instructions and it worked, thanks very much for the tips!

Comment: Cool, I've struggled with it myself so I was familiar with it. :)